# Rails: building object from has_many associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, has-one

I think it might be a syntax problem.

1. I have a `Event.rb` model:

   ```
   class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :members
    has_one :brazusc
   end
   ```

   A `Member.rb`:

   ```
   class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
   end
   ```

   And a `Brazusc.rb` model:

   ```
   class Brazusc < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
   end
   ```

What I am trying to do: `member.events.build_brazusc`, but I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `build_brazusc' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f99517d4a78>
```

How would I build an object from the `has_many` association?

2. I am also trying to retrieve the associated model from a `has_many/has_one` association, like this: `member.events.brazusc`, since `brazusc` has an `event_id`, but I get:

   ```
   NoMethodError: undefined method `leads' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f99517d4a78>
   ```

How can I retrieve the object (`brazusc`) that is associated with `event`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you did not ask a question.

Comment: Made my question clear, @AndreyDeineko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
new_brazusc = member.events.find_by(name: "Brazusc")
new_brazusc.build_brazusc.save
```